# What happended to nunit extensions/rowtest?

Tags: nunit, nunit-2.5, rowtest

In NUnit 2.4.7, nunit.framework.extensions.dll was included which made it possible to do RowTests.

When downloading the newest version (2.5.8) I can't find it. What happened to it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Instead of using `RowTest`, you can use `TestCase`. A previous testing using `RowTest` would look like:

```cs
[RowTest]
[Row("foo", false)]
[Row("", true)]
public void Some_test(string value, bool expected)
{
  // test
}
```

And the same thing with `TestCase` looks like this:

```cs
[TestCase("foo", false)]
[TestCase("", true)]
public void Some_test(string value, bool expected)
{
  // test
}
```

Answer (score 5):

RowTest was an extension that was merged in temporarily, and was removed in 2.5 Alpha 2

Quote from the [Release Notes for 2.4.8](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.4.8):

> NUnit now includes the RowTest
>   extension, written by Andreas
>   Schlapsi, in it's extension
>   assemblies. This extension allows you
>   to write test methods that take
>   arguments and to provide multiple sets
>   of argument values using the
>   RowAttribute. To use RowTest, your
>   test must reference the
>   nunit.framework.extensions assembly.
>
> Note: Merging extensions into NUnit's
>   own extension assembly is an
>   experiment we are trying for this
>   release. The approach may change in
>   future releases.future releases.

Quote from the [2.5 alpha 2 Release Notes](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5.1):

> The RowTestExtension, which was merged
>   into the nunit extension dlls in
>   Alpha-1, is now provided as a separate
>   addin. This is the general approach we
>   plan to take with regard to any
>   bundled addins, since it permits the
>   creator of an addin to provide updates
>   separately from the NUnit release.

You can now download the RowTest extension from [here](http://code.google.com/p/rowtest-extension/downloads/list).